# Password login issue, can’t open grub

Tags: grub2, password, recovery-mode, password-recovery

So I changed my password using the command line using using the `passwd` command. I restarted and cannot login using the new password or any of my old passwords so I am unable to use my computer. I have tried restarting in recovery mode, however, I can’t get to the grub screen. Hitting the left shift button has never worked (my computer is too fast) and hitting the escape button only gets me to the startup menu. I use a hp pavilion laptop. Ubuntu is the only OS on it. I removed windows and used a usb with Ubuntu on it for installation. I believe I’m on Ubuntu 20.04 but am unsure because I can’t login. Any help would be great!

Comment: try booting up on a separate LiveCD instance, such as using the DVD image, then you can check the /var/log/* log files, to see what error is coming up when you attempt (and fail) to login.

Comment: I do not know the answer to any of those question. Maybe I’m not familiar with the terminology. I assume I’m using the desktop version, but I don’t know how to tell. When I login I just click on my profile and type my password in. Hope that’s enough info.

Comment: Can you login to a command line tetminal? `Ctrl-Alt-F3`, hit `Enter`? If so, change your password back to the original. Logout, `Ctrl-Alt-F1` back to the GUI, login, use System Settings (the gear icon in the top right corner of the screen), and use Users&Accounts to change your password.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I may have accidentally hit an extra key when I changed my password so I think I need to reset it.

Comment: Be aware that whenever you reset a password with that method you mat successfully login with the new password, the expected result, but you won't have access to your personal files. After all that's what passwords are for. You may *change* your password from *within* a running session anytime you want via GUI or command line.